# is there a nicer oneliner for handling "unless somthing.nil? || something[:key].nil?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to make this one liner better looking?

```
@var = params[:key1][:key2] unless params.blank? || params[:key1].blank?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, thanks for all the replies!

I'm going to sum up the answers - as the answer seems more subtle than just another oneliner ;-)

As gertas point out that params is always present in a controller action (which is indeed where I'm working), and that nil check is enough, my original code can thus be reduced to:

```
@var = params[:key1][:key2] unless params[:key1].nil?
```

This is quite readable but not as short as other suggestions, like

```
params[:key1].nil? || (@var = params[:key1][:key2])

@var =  params[:key1] && params[:key1][:key2]
```

or even

```
@var = (params[:key1] || {})[:key2]
```

I wondered how to use rubys try() method on hashes, and hellvinz gave the answer (rewritten to match my new/realized need):

```
@var = params[:key1].try(:fetch, :key2, nil)
```

Finally, Shinya Miyazaki came up with some interesting variations using fetch and merge:

```
@var = params.fetch(:key1, {}).fetch(:key2, nil)

@var = {:key1=>{}}.merge(params)[:key1][:key2]
```

I ended up going with "my own", to honor the principle of "Clarity over Brevity" as pointed out by Chris McCauley

Thanks again everyone! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

```
@var =  params && params[:key1] && params[:key1][:key2]
```

Comment: In your case `=` will be done in any way, but in questioner's — only when right from `unless` is equal to `false`

Comment: This works really well for testing for `.nil?` values but not for `.blank?`

Comment: good refactoring, although i think the original one is more 'readable' or understandable with one look. but nonetheless, good refactor

Comment: @Shadwell: checking if params[:key1] is blank is not neccessary, nil check is enough - we want to avoid exception here, on blank hash asking for :key2 gives nil which is ok

Comment: Anyway it works wrong. If some params lack, @var will become false, but do we need it?

Comment: Anyway it deletes previous value.

Comment: The OP's code assigns the value of  params[:key1][:key2] to @var, doesn't this code lose that?

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the replies :-) As gertas point out that params is always present in a controller action (which is indeed where I'm working), and that nil check is enough, my original code can be reduced to @var = params[:key1][:key2] unless params[:key1].nil?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
params.blank? || params[:key1].blank? || (@var = params[:key1][:key2])
```

But your way is more readable for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just to let you know that you can also do this, but i'm not sure it is better looking :) (and you have to be in ror):

```
@var = params.try(:fetch, :key1, nil).try(:fetch, :key2, nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clarity over Brevity!

Before changing your original code, ask yourself if the next person reading your code would find your code more or less comprehensible than the alternatives suggested here.

Personally I'd go with your original.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using it in controller (params allways present - not nil):

`@var = (params[:key1] || {})[:key2]`

Comment: actually this is not hack, it is used all around Rails and gems

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple idea.

```
@var = params.fetch(:key1, {}).fetch(:key2, nil)
```

Using `merge` is interesting.

```
@var = {:key1=>{}}.merge(params)[:key1][:key2]
```