# Check for nil warns about unexpected nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null

I have the following check for nil:

```
client = !deal['deal']['party']['party'].nil? ? deal['deal']['party']['party']['company_id'] : ""
```

but still I get:

> You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
>   You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
>   The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]

How can I prevent this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a nicer oneliner for handling "unless somthing.nil? || something\[:key\].nil?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725186/is-there-a-nicer-oneliner-for-handling-unless-somthing-nil-somethingkey-n)

Comment: *Don’t answer questions that have already been answered elsewhere. Yeah, you might earn a couple of points of reputation, but, because you are duplicating content, you are actually making the internet worse.* (c) Jeff

Comment: That wasn't my question, I wasn't looking for something "nicer" I just ran into trouble finding out why my check on nil kept returning an unexpected nil error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know Ruby, but I think it goes wrong before the .nil:

```
deal['deal']['party']['party']
    ^       ^        ^
```

The arrows indicate possible nil indexes. For example, what if ["deal"] is nil or the first ["party"] is nil?

Comment: True, the first [party] was nil. Tnx:)

Answer (score 2):

By checking `!deal.nil?` and `!deal['deal'].nil?` and `!deal['deal']['party'].nil?` and `!deal['deal']['party']['party'].nil?`

Comment: Ouch, that's really not scalable or pretty

Comment: Well, you're right, but it is at least a solution to the problem! :)

Comment: This at least helped me find out where I was wrong. I'm not going to implement this, because the array structure is fixed. But I had to check on the first party entity, not it's child.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at the `andand` game:

http://andand.rubyforge.org/

Comment: This looks interesting but I don't quite understand it. This would help to shorten the syntax for checking every layer of the array right?

Comment: Yes, that's what it's for. I just added the link because "nightcracker" already pointed out what the problem was.

Comment: Luckily I just had to check for the correct child, not every layer, but I've saved the suggestion, tnx:)

Answer (score 0):

At each step, you can use an appropriate method built in `NilClass` to escape from nil, if it were array, string, or numeric. Just add `to_hash` to the inventory of this list and use it.

```
class NilClass; def to_hash; {} end end
client = deal['deal'].to_hash['party'].to_hash['party'].to_hash['company_id'].to_s
```

You can also do:

```
client = deal.fetch('deal', {}).fecth('party', {}).fetch('party', {}).fetch('company_id', '')
```